# Java throws NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a text file where first two lines are integers `m` and `n`, then there are `m` lines that each has `n` pipe-delimited values. I wrote a program that reads the file and creates `m*n` array with the values from the file, and it worked fine for bajillion times, and then out of sudden, with the same code, with the same file, it threw `NumberFormatException` while reading the integer from the first line. The whole code is here:

```
public class Thegame extends JFrame {
    public Integer st;
    public Integer el;
    public String[][] tab;

    public Thegame(String pth)
    {
        setSize(640,480);
        setTitle(pth);
        File file = new File(pth);
        try
        {
            BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            st = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine());
            el = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine());
            tab = new String[st][el];
            for(Integer i=0; i<st; i++)
            {
                String lin = rdr.readLine();
                StringTokenizer spl = new StringTokenizer(lin,"|");
                for(Integer j=0; j<el; j++)
                {
                    tab[i][j] = spl.nextToken();
                }                
            }
            rdr.close();            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What really worries me is that the same code worked okay before and out of nowhere it turned out to be bad, so I can't even tell what exactly is wrong...

Comment: What string is causing the NumberFormatException?

Comment: Yeah, would you care to post the stack trace you get with the Exception? Also, a copy of the file you are reading.

Comment: I'm sure "for no reason" is a very strong statement... Can you do some simple System.out.println on the strings you are trying to parse? (the results of rdr.readLine())?

Comment: You should define your loops like so: `for(int i=0; i<st; i++)` there is no reason to use `Integer` it will only slow down your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must've changed, otherwise it's magic. Possible suspects:

- the content of the input file has changed. Have you checked it with some kind of hex editor. Does the file start with digits indeed?
- Java/system locale have changed. What previously was treated as a number, no longer is a number in the new locale. Typical catches with locale are thousands separators (,).

Answer (score 1):

The two possible problem lines are:

```
st = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine());
el = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine());
```

You need to make sure that what the reader is reading is actually an `Integer`.

Try the following small modification:

```
st = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine().trim());
el = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine().trim());
```

If that doesn't fix it, you need to make sure that you are capturing the correct input.

To help debug the problem, it may be helpful to save the input to a string and print it to see what it looks like before trying to parse it:

```
String stStr = rdr.readLine().trim()
System.out.println(stStr);
st = Integer.valueOf(stStr);
System.out.println(stStr);
String elStr = rdr.readLine().trim();
el = Integer.valueOf(elStr);
```

If the values that are printed aren't integers, then you are getting the input incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't happen to somehow get some special characters placed before the first line in the file did you?  I know I had that issue once and it took me forever to figure out what was going on.  I think notepad++ will let you see if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

If the behavior changed, something did change.

If the code hasn't changed then either:

- The file being read changed: look for special (non readable) characters with a hex editor. If you have an input file that doesn’t cause the exception, then compare it with the one that does (again, hex comparison).
- The java environment changed: check for changes in your Java virtual machine configuration, specially the [locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
       st = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine());
        el = Integer.valueOf(rdr.readLine());
```

to be

```
 String input = rdr.readLine();
 try {
     st = Integer.valueOf( input);
 } catch( NumberFormatException  e){
    System.out.println( "exception reading " + input );
 }
 input = rdr.readLine();
 try {
     el = Integer.valueOf(input);
 } catch( NumberFormatException  e){
    System.out.println( "exception reading " + input );
 }
```

and you'll get your answer of what the problem string is printed out.